# "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when it is pass to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-context

how can I able to get the return value for this, I tried the forEach, but every time I pass the loop to images variable I always get this error ("Cannot read property 'map/forEach' of undefined")

```
        // console logging displays the image file url
        let images = imagesArray.map(image => console.log(image.fields.file.url)) 
        imagesArray.map(image => console.log(image.fields.file.url))

        // but when i pass it to a variable, i got this error (Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)
        let images = imagesArray.map(image => image.fields.file.url)
```

here is the method i have. the let response and let itemList is in another method
calling the formatData with the response.items as the argument. I'm using contentful in this context

```
let response = await Client.getEntries({ content_type: "customersItemList" })
let itemList = this.formatData(response.items)

formatData(items){ // used in componentDidMount
    if(items){}
    let tempItemList = items.map(item => {
        let id = item.sys.id
        const imagesArray = item.fields.images
        imagesArray.map(image => console.log(image.fields.file.url))
        let images = imagesArray.map(image => image.fields.file.url)

        let customer = {...item.fields, images: images, id: id}
        return customer
    })

    return tempItemList
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger.

Comment: I think there is some missing context. What is `imagesArray`? Are you seeing the problem after the `console.log` `map` to `images`?

Comment: Show What's in imagesArray? Then we might help you

Comment: my bad, I've done some edit to my question so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

We need further information to help you.
what is imagesArray, is it an array of HTMLImageElement ? is it created manually or is it a return of some api ? try to console.log the imagesArray just before the map and see if it is indeed undefined

All we can tell from your code snippet is that it should works, unless it is a sharedArray reference which is shared across multiple workers and got its state mutated elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is that items array is null, that's why you got the error so what you want to do is

```
formatData(items){ // used in componentDidMount
    if(!items){
       return null;
    }
    let tempItemList = items.map(item => {
        let id = item.sys.id
        const imagesArray = item.fields.images
        imagesArray.map(image => console.log(image.fields.file.url))
        let images = imagesArray.map(image => image.fields.file.url)

        let customer = {...item.fields, images: images, id: id}
        return customer
    })

    return tempItemList
}
```